# Detect if element is in viewport iOs

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I know, there are many questions regarding this topic.
But I haven't found a solution so far. My code is working in every browser/system except iOs Safari (tested on iPhone 6s, 7 - iOS 12.1.1).

I uploaded a version on my webspace: http://www.maximilian-neuse.de/viewport/

When the red area gets into the viewport, the blue one should turn green.
As said, working perfectly on all systems (Windows, Mac) except on iOs Safari.

There is a difference of 195px (the light red area shows the point of the switch).

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
div { height: 100vh; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.red { background: red; position: relative; }
.red::before { content:''; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 195px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); position: absolute; }
.green { background: green; }
```

**JS**

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('.red').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $( ".blue" ).addClass( "green" );
    } else {
      $( ".blue" ).removeClass( "green" );
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9dLh8pz/

Comment: reproduced in Safari iOS 12.1.1 iPhone 8